# SecurityException with targestsdk lower than 23 (20)

Tags: android

I'm getting this error :

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
```

I have these permissions in my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I have never experienced this error until android 6. (It actually occurred only once with Android 5.)

The thing is my targestSdk is lower than 23, it is 20, so I thought I shouldn't experience this kind or problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is that you are running this on an 6.0+ emulator and you have a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher.

In that case, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` are part of [the Android 6.0 runtime permission system](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html). Either revise your app to participate in this system, or drop your targetSdkVersion below 23.

Comment: Then use only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Answer (score 0):

That can happen on Android 6. If the application is build with SDK lower than 23, the developer does not have access to checking permission API. When installing such application on Android 6, all permission are set to true. However the phone user can still go to settings and turn the permission off (he gets popup that application might crash, when the permission is off because it is incompatible with permissions revoking).

You can either update your app (this is the better option), or just leave the problem as it is.

Comment: By updating my app you mean increasing the targetSdk to 23 and show the request permission pop-up if needed?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. The Android SDK is changing and we should react to it.

Comment: How come it doesn't crash on all android 6 devices? just specific cases

Comment: By default your app on all Android 6 devices have permissions set to true. If You manually disable it, the app will crash.

Comment: that's weird...I am trying to recreate the crash, but not succeeding. I went to settings , location, and disabled the gps. It still doesn't crash on my device with android 6

Comment: Maybe You have hardened the code by try/catch? By saying "the app will crash" I meant that the functionality will not be able to be accesed. Your exception it is a non-fatal one.

Comment: Nope I haven't touched it.. I wanted to recreate it so I could debug it better. But I can't get it to happen :/

Comment: it crashes upon 'deny' for some reason :/

Comment: Probably the `SecurityException` is thrown.

Comment: but I've updated the targetSdk to 23. Then before connecting to GoogleApiClient instance, I check if location permission exists and android version is at least 6. Then I if the user presses 'deny' I just don't  do anything( return; ). However, it seems at though the onConnected callback method is still called, and that's when the SecurityException is thrown

Comment: So the exception must be different. Is you logcat showing any error?

Comment: no, it's showing the exact same exception.. so weird

Comment: the weird thing is that after pressing 'deny' it pop up the pop-up again , then if you press deny again, it opens it once again.... and after a few times like this it crashes